# Fechar dropdown com a tecla ESC

Tags: jquery

Seria possível fazer com o que o dropdown abaixo, fechasse com a tecla ESC?

```js
$("#jq-dropdown-1").on("contextmenu", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    var a = $("a[data-jq-dropdown='#jq-dropdown-1']");
    
    if(!$(a).hasClass("jq-dropdown-open")){
      $(this).toggle();
      $(a).toggleClass("jq-dropdown-open");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1">Dropdown</a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando um evento com `keyCode`:

```
$(window).on('keypress',function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==27){
        $("#jq-dropdown-1").toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: Like, mas utilizando o toggle, quando precionar "Esc" novamente era abrir o Dropdown.

Comment: Verdade, não tinha pensado nisso, mas nada que um `if()` para verificar se o dropdown esta aberto não resolva